# How to give the camera's edge collision in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

I am making a 2D game in Unity, and in this game, the camera will not need to move. As such, I would like to constrain the player's movement within the camera border, preferably with collision instead of just based on the player's transform. Honestly, I have no idea where to start doing something like this, but I assume it would involve some scripting. I am pretty comfortable with scripting at this point, but if your answer includes scripting, I would appreciate it if it would include thorough explanations of everything that is going on. By the by, I am using C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the camera is in orthographic mode, you can use [`EdgeCollider2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EdgeCollider2D.html) to do this, finding the world positions of the corners of the screen using `ScreenToWorldPoint` to then determine the shape of the `EdgeCollider2D`.

The [Unity Community UnityLibrary Github](https://github.com/UnityCommunity/UnityLibrary/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/2D/Colliders/ScreenEdgeColliders.cs) has [an example](https://github.com/UnityCommunity/UnityLibrary/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/2D/Colliders/ScreenEdgeColliders.cs) (copied below):

```
// adds EdgeCollider2D colliders to screen edges
// only works with orthographic camera

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace UnityLibrary
{
  public class ScreenEdgeColliders : MonoBehaviour 
  {
    void Awake () 
    {
      AddCollider();
    }

    void AddCollider () 
    {
      if (Camera.main==null) {Debug.LogError("Camera.main not found, failed to create edge colliders"); return;}

      var cam = Camera.main;
      if (!cam.orthographic) {Debug.LogError("Camera.main is not Orthographic, failed to create edge colliders"); return;}

      var bottomLeft = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var topLeft = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, cam.pixelHeight, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var topRight = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth, cam.pixelHeight, cam.nearClipPlane));
      var bottomRight = (Vector2)cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(cam.pixelWidth, 0, cam.nearClipPlane));

      // add or use existing EdgeCollider2D
      var edge = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>()==null?gameObject.AddComponent<EdgeCollider2D>():GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();

      var edgePoints = new [] {bottomLeft,topLeft,topRight,bottomRight, bottomLeft};
      edge.points = edgePoints;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering another one of my questions, @Ruzihm. I was just wondering, in the line that says `var edge = GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>()==null?gameObject.AddComponent<EdgeCollider2D>():GetComponent<EdgeCollider2D>();`,  what does the `:` do?

Comment: its part of an: 'if-then-else' shorthand statement. Good for simple one line conditions

Comment: @Ruzihm your solution clearly works if I attach the script to an empty GO with transform of (0,0,0), but when I attach the script on a Canvas element (for example the Panel that it's shown when I want to instantiate those colliders) the colliders positions are wrong, even if the canvas element is displayed above the whole screen (anchors on camera corners) why is that?